# How to deserialise JSON from HubSpot

Tags: c#, json, hubspot

I am having trouble deserializing JSON received from HubSpot ContactList API.

I am using Restsharp and NewtonSoft, and I'm having real struggles understanding how to correctly define the required classes in order to deserialize the JSON string, which is below:

```
  "contacts": [
    {
      "vid": 2251,
      "portal-id": 5532227,
      "is-contact": true,
      "profile-url": "https://app.hubspot.com/contacts/5532227/contact/2251",
      "properties": {
        "firstname": {
          "value": "Carl"
        },
        "lastmodifieddate": {
          "value": "1554898386040"
        },
        "company": {
          "value": "Cygnus Project"
        },
        "lastname": {
          "value": "Swann"
        }
      },
      "form-submissions": [],
      "identity-profiles": [
        {
          "vid": 2251,
          "saved-at-timestamp": 1553635648634,
          "deleted-changed-timestamp": 0,
          "identities": [
            {
              "type": "EMAIL",
              "value": "cswann@cygnus.co.uk",
              "timestamp": 1553635648591,
              "is-primary": true
            },
            {
              "type": "LEAD_GUID",
              "value": "e2345",
              "timestamp": 1553635648630
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "merge-audits": []
    },
    {
      "vid": 2301,
      "portal-id": 5532227,
      "is-contact": true,
      "profile-url": "https://app.hubspot.com/contacts/5532227/contact/2301",
      "properties": {
        "firstname": {
          "value": "Carlos"
        },
        "lastmodifieddate": {
          "value": "1554886333954"
        },
        "company": {
          "value": "Khaos Control"
        },
        "lastname": {
          "value": "Swannington"
        }
      },
      "identity-profiles": [
        {
          "vid": 2301,
          "saved-at-timestamp": 1553635648733,
          "deleted-changed-timestamp": 0,
          "identities": [
            {
              "type": "EMAIL",
              "value": "cswann@khaoscontrol.com",
              "timestamp": 1553635648578,
              "is-primary": true
            },
            {
              "type": "LEAD_GUID",
              "value": "c7f403ba",
              "timestamp": 1553635648729
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "merge-audits": []
    }
  ],
  "has-more": false,
  "vid-offset": 2401
}
```

If I simply request the vid, I correctly get 2 vid's back. It's when I try to do the properties and that i get a fail.

Please help

Comment: Try to get class structure for your json from http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp)

Comment: I won't flag as a duplicate of this (or the above), but have a read of this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object  You can deserialize JSON into a `dynamic` object so you don't need to define a class.

Comment: @ER , for a grinder of Json Csv dupe. I found you hard on that one. Json2Csharp limit is those dictionary string, string thingy. And that the issue here.

Comment: @Swanne, building an [MCVE], you can reduce your json to the only part that cause the issue the `properties`. From that point it will be clearer what you issue is. You will then have to determine the way you want to solve it. I will go for droping the value and store the data in a dictionary<string, string> this way you have the property only once and their value store as text till you know what the type should be.

Comment: @Swanne, Did you tried my answer below? Let me know if you faced any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets reduce the Json to the minimum to reproduce your error :

```
{
    "vid": 2301,
    "portal-id": 5532227,
    "is-contact": true,
    "profile-url": "https://app.hubspot.com/contacts/5532227/contact/2301",
    "properties": {
        "firstname": {
            "value": "Carlos"
        },
        "lastmodifieddate": {
            "value": "1554886333954"
        },
        "company": {
            "value": "Khaos Control"
        },
        "lastname": {
            "value": "Swannington"
        }
    }
}
```

And the appropriate class `ContactListAPI_Result`:

```
public partial class ContactListAPI_Result
{
    [JsonProperty("vid")]
    public long Vid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("portal-id")]
    public long PortalId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("is-contact")]
    public bool IsContact { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("profile-url")]
    public Uri ProfileUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("properties")]
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> Properties { get; set; }
}

public partial class ContactListAPI_Result
{
    public static ContactListAPI_Result FromJson(string json) 
        => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContactListAPI_Result>(json);
    //public static ContactListAPI_Result FromJson(string json) 
    //  => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContactListAPI_Result>(json, Converter.Settings);
}

public static void toto()
{
    string input = @"    {
    ""vid"": 2301,
    ""portal-id"": 5532227,
    ""is-contact"": true,
    ""profile-url"": ""https://app.hubspot.com/contacts/5532227/contact/2301"",
    ""properties"": {
        ""firstname"": {
            ""value"": ""Carlos""
        },
        ""lastmodifieddate"": {
            ""value"": ""1554886333954""
        },
        ""company"": {
            ""value"": ""Khaos Control""
        },
        ""lastname"": {
            ""value"": ""Swannington""
        }
    }
}";

    var foo = ContactListAPI_Result.FromJson(input);
}
```

But the Value of one property will be burrow in the sub dictionary, we can the project the object in a more usefull one :

```
public partial class ItemDTO
{
    public long Vid { get; set; }
    public long PortalId { get; set; }
    public bool IsContact { get; set; }
    public Uri ProfileUrl { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

Adding the projection to the Class:

```
public ItemDTO ToDTO()
{
    return new ItemDTO
    {
        Vid = Vid,
        PortalId = PortalId,
        IsContact = IsContact,
        ProfileUrl = ProfileUrl,
        Properties = 
            Properties.ToDictionary(
                p => p.Key, 
                p => p.Value["value"]
            )
    };
}
```

Usage :

```
var result = foo.ToDTO();
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6wNvor)

Comment: Will add a online Demo when I get back from my break. If you have any question.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to assist. An online demo will most certainly be very useful. I look forward to it. Thank you again

Comment: @Swanne, [live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6wNvor). Basically copy pasted from the answer directly

Comment: Thank you. I am getting some strange errors. My project is a winforms project and the error messages seem to point to that. Any idea?

Comment: @Swanne, That's a really vague description. It's like Calling a doctor just saying the word "pain". Do you have any indication of where? What kind of error? Winform/Console/WPF will all behave.

Comment: If I had to make a guess, I will say in `ContactListAPI_Result FromJson` remove the `=>` add a `return` and don't forget the `{}`. Like in the live demo.

Comment: Hey @xdtTransform. Thank you very much for all of your help. I really appreciate it. I used your code to successfully achieve what I set out to do. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Creating and managing class structure for big and nested key/value pair json is tedious task

So one approach is to use `JToken` instead.

You can simply parse your JSON to `JToken` and by [querying](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) parsed object, you will easily read the data that you want without creating class structure for your json

From your post it seems you need to retrieve `vid` and `properties` from your json so try below code,

```
string json = "Your json here";

JToken jToken = JToken.Parse(json);

var result = jToken["contacts"].ToObject<JArray>()
    .Select(x => new
    {
        vid = Convert.ToInt32(x["vid"]),
        properties = x["properties"].ToObject<Dictionary<string, JToken>>()
                                    .Select(y => new
                                    {
                                       Key = y.Key,
                                       Value = y.Value["value"].ToString()
                                    }).ToList()
    }).ToList();


//-----------Print the result to console------------

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.vid);

    foreach (var prop in item.properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Key + " - " + prop.Value);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

**Output:**

[image]